# API key access rights on ***

Tags: rest, authentication

I [read on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) the following:

> The API key often acts as both a unique identifier and a secret token for authentication, *and will generally have a set of access rights on the API associated with it and `***`*.

Is `***` a typo? Or does it mean anything in the context of API keys and/or authentication?

Comment: looking at [edit history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Application_programming_interface_key&type=revision&diff=956069260&oldid=928963720) seems to hint at it being a typo.

Comment: It is definitely a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit to the people in the comments for pointing this out. I didn't want to take the credit for it so I'll add to it and write a more detailed answer.

The edit history started with the line as:
`a set of access rights on the API associated with it.`
Then it was changed to:
`a set of access rights on the API associated with it and.`
Then it was changed to:
`a set of access rights on the API associated with it and ***`
So it appears to be a typo.